# Is there a way to have mapped types and a specific property?

Tags: typescript

I had in mind something like this:

```
type Foo<T, K extends string> = K extends "isDirty"
  ? never
  : {
      [P in K]: T;
      isDirty: boolean;
    };
```

But Typescript still doesn't know that `K` will never be `"isDirty".

What I wanted to do is, allow any key value, so it could be `foo`, `bar`, `potatoes` and have that be of type `T`. But also have the property `isDirty: boolean`, so `K` can have any value but that.

Some examples:

```
const foo: Foo<number, "bar"> = {
  bar: 5,
  isDirty: false
}

const potatoes: Foo<number[], "potatoes"> = {
  potatoes: [1,6,15],
  isDirty: false
}
```

Is this possible to do in Typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of `{[P in K]: T}` and `{isDirty: boolean}`:

```typescript
type Foo<T, K extends string> = K extends "isDirty"
    ? never
    : {
          [P in K]: T;
      } & {
          isDirty: boolean;
      };

const foo: Foo<number, "bar"> = {
    bar: 5,
    isDirty: false,
};

const potatoes: Foo<number[], "potatoes"> = {
    potatoes: [1, 6, 15],
    isDirty: false,
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAPAFQDRQNJQgD2BAOwBMBnKE4AJwEsCBzAPigF5Ns9DSoAiakgEWqVQ3AFBQJUAPxQCEAG4RK4yQC4oAbxWSdUANoAFKLUwBddcgDc2yQF8oAMk03dxgUNDqARggA2EAEMCa1dba1EAYzgCCigAMwR1eCQCAFcAWy8ldG4vAMpuJlYtHTzKdQBWVBs+QWEQdTiA3xIIarDRSOjYsDhgAOA4CBIkhEQ0zKU9Uxze-sHhwpZnHTmBoZH9AEZ0ADZ0LYqZmvd6xubW9ssgA)

Comment: So the reason that it works here is because we guarantee that `isDirty` will be of type `boolean` due to it being an intersection ?

Comment: @LoyalPotato - Right. You already had the conditional there to ensure that `K` didn't include `"isDirty"`, so there won't be an `isDirty` in `{]P in K]: T}`, and then we intersect that type with one that has `isDirty: boolean`. BTW, if you wanted to, you could make it possible to define more than one property, either with a type as in your original code (https://tsplay.dev/mAxQQN) or using a do-nothing function (but I've just been urgently called away, I'll come back to show that option).

Comment: @LoyalPotato - Here's that function version that avoid repetition: https://tsplay.dev/wXrjOm

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the extra uses cases :)